# need help in jquery unformjs select menu '&' character encoding

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, character-encoding, uniform

I am using uniformjs form controls which are working except the listmenu. When i add '&' symbol (&) inthe list menu, it renders correctly, but problem is coming when i change the value to different value and select again the value which has & symbol it renders as `&amp;` instead '&' symbol in the list menu.
[image]

[image]

```
<select>
<option>Through &amp; Google</option>
<option>Through Twitter</option>
<option>Other&hellip;</option>         
<option>&lt;Hi&gt;</option>
</select>
```

http://uniformjs.com/#example

can someone tell me what is the problem..

Comment: Is the ampersand represrnted as an entity in the markup ? `<option>One &amp; Two</option>` ?

Comment: @Didier G. I did tried both ways <option>One &amp; Two</option> and <option>One & Two</option>, but both the problem still retains..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem might come from this line ([source](https://github.com/pixelmatrix/uniform/blob/master/jquery.uniform.js) - line 185):

```
spanTag.text(elem.find(":selected").html());
```

If you have the following html:

```
<select>
    <option>One &amp; Two</option>
    <option>One & Two</option>
</select>
```

1. The plugin gets the content as **html** doing `elem.find(":selected").html()`

   Both option element will return this value when getting html: `One &amp; Two`
   Special characters are represented by html entities (`&amp;`for `&` in our example)
2. and then plugin applies this result as **text** using `spanTag.text(<html>);`

   So html entities do not get parsed (`&amp;` is displayed as `&amp;`)

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/4znhB/) illustrates it.

I don't think there is a solution to that except to not use special characters like `&`...

Answer (score 4):

According to Didler, why not modify the uniformjs a little bit?

I have met the same scenario recently, and thanks Didler to point out the exact line which saves me heaps of time to locate the place.

In my case, I have a select with value consists of special characters, such as:

```
<option>aaa</option>
<option><a>bbb<br>ddd<hr>ccc</option>
```

So that I modify the code in line 185 to:

```
spanTag.text(elem.find(":selected").text());
```

which solves the problem that when render the value it is in a correct shape.

In op's scenario, I'm not sure which server side language you are using, but definitely there is a way to escape the text within option before generating the html page so that there is no `&amp;` in your html but the character itself. 
I'm using Java so that I can simply use JSTL `<c:out value="${******}"/>` to put the value in the option tag.

Comment: am using cold fusion for generating this options

Answer (score 4):

There's a pull request ([130](https://github.com/pixelmatrix/uniform/pull/130/files)) that updates 4 lines of code (lines 173, 185, 212, and 569) so that instead of using `.html()` they use `.text()`. The two later pull requests I saw don't seem to update all 4 lines.

If you wish to update the minified version as well, you can search for these two snippets:

- `l.html(n.html()` (x1 - change second instance of 'html')
- `:selected").html(` (x3 - change only instance of 'html')